# Getting redirected intermediate URL https://mydomain.secure.force.com/secur/weakhttps.jsp?l=1

Tags: force.com-sites, exception, tls

I have implemented a gateway for my site. We send request to gateway and gateway send response msg. but recently we are not getting response and when checked in logs of gateway we found an error

```
An exception occured in HTTPProcess sendMessage: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://mydomain.secure.force.com/secur/weakhttps.jsp?l=1
```

The gateway is sending its response to a different URL (https://mydomain.secure.force.com/ResponseHandlingPage) but i am not getting how is it ending up at https://mydomain.secure.force.com/secur/weakhttps.jsp?l=1

I tried to do little search about this error, My best guess is TLS protocol not being respected while sending response Msg to salesforce.

Anybody seen this error and what it means actually? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that Salesforce is discouraging using `TLS 1.0` protocol.

Please use `TLS 1.1` or `TLS 1.2` protocol in the gateway you implemented.

You can find more information [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1)

> Salesforce is requiring an upgrade to TLS 1.1 or higher beginning July 22, 2017, in order to align with industry best practices for
>   security and data integrity. Action is required prior to this date to
>   prevent any disruption to your production instance. Once your
>   organization has taken all the necessary steps and upgraded, disable
>   TLS 1.0 by activating the the TLS 1.0 Critical Update. You can find
>   instructions on activating the Critical Update (CRUC) in the TLS 1.0
>   Critical Update (CRUC) Setting article.
>
> This article contains all of the information currently available on
>   Salesforce's disablement of the TLS 1.0 encryption protocol. This
>   article will be updated as new information becomes available. Please
>   check back often for guidance on preparing for TLS 1.0 disablement.
>   For other Salesforce Services such as: Marketing
>   Cloud/Heroku/Pardot/SalesforceIQ/etc, TLS 1.0 disablement is currently
>   being evaluated. More information will follow once plans and deadlines
>   have been finalized. The November 11, 2017, phase of Salesforce’s
>   planned disablement of TLS 1.0 has been completed. If you are
>   experiencing issues connecting between Salesforce and any
>   integrations, browsers, or other third-party applications, please log
>   a case with Support via the Help & Training portal. If this is a
>   critical production issue affecting all users, please call Support to
>   log a Severity 1 case.
>
> A subset of users attempting to login via browsers that are not
>   compliant with TLS 1.1 or higher may not have the ability to log a
>   case through the Help & Training portal. In this event, please call
>   1-800-NOSOFTWARE to log a case. This article was last updated on
>   November 24, 2017.

or [here](https://trust.salesforce.com/en/security/disabling-tls-1-0/)

LS Disablement Has Begun: What You Need to Know
Salesforce has begun the phased disablement of the TLS 1.0 encryption protocol. To continue uninterrupted access to Salesforce after your disablement date, we require that all customers support a more secure version of TLS for all orgs. TLS 1.1 will be the new minimum standard security protocol used by Salesforce in order to align with industry-wide best practices for security and data integrity.

Note: To give Administrators more time to prepare Salesforce Community users, the TLS 1.0 disablement deadline for Salesforce Communities has been extended to March 2018.

> The impact of the TLS 1.0 disablement will vary by org, and depends on
>   the ways in which your users connect to the Salesforce service.
>   Upgrade to TLS version 1.1 now to ensure uninterrupted access to all
>   of your Salesforce orgs. Key areas of impact include:
>
> User browser access could be interrupted as browser incompatibility
>   may prevent your internal users from accessing salesforce.com.
>   Microsoft email integrations such as Salesforce for Outlook, Exchange
>   Sync and Salesforce App for Outlook won’t work if users don’t meet
>   compatibility requirements. API integrations will cease to work if
>   they are not compatible with TLS 1.1 or later. This includes
>   .NET-based integrations that send requests to Salesforce and are not
>   enabled with TLS 1.1 and/or TLS 1.2. Communities and Sites users will
>   not be able to connect unless their browser or browser settings are
>   updated per compatibility guidelines. Please review How to test for
>   internet browser compatibility for more information. Partner
>   App/AppExchange integrations will cease to work if they are not
>   compatible with TLS 1.1 or later. Resources for a smooth transition to
>   TLS 1.1 or higher
>
> Read the Salesforce Disabling TLS 1.0 article for more details on this
>   important change TLS 1.0 Disablement Readiness Checklist (PDF) for
>   best practices on how to prepare for this change Listen to our
>   security experts talk about how TLS disablement may impact you
>   (recording here) Listen to the recording of how to effectively
>   troubleshoot issues related to the TLS 1.0 disablement (recording
>   here) Ask questions and share best practices within the Official:
>   Salesforce Infrastructure Success Community Group

and [here](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150M000003KgGkQAK) or [here](https://admin.salesforce.com/tls-1-0-disablement-what-you-need-to-know) and [overall schedule here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=TLS-1-0-Disablement-Schedule&type=1)

Comment: We already are using TLS 1.1      Response is coming from Java 1.6 based Gateway and in salesforce TLS 1.0 is already deactivated.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using TLS 1.1? I believe you need higher version of Java to use TLS 1.1 as default value. If you are using TLS 1.1 and Java 6 you have to specify in your java virtual machine startup parameters or in java code that you want to use TLS 1.1 - despite it is available to use in Java 6, it is not set as default

Answer (score 1):

You could ensure that you are using the right TLS Protocol by manually setting this before sending your request. You can find some details on this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391798/how-to-set-tls-version-on-apache-httpclient). I hope this helps resolve your issue.